# PHP - connect netfond API through PHP SSL socket connection

Tags: php, api, sockets, ssl

I am not sure if we can connect to netfond API through PHP , because on this link ( http://www.netfonds.no/api.php ) they have given python file as an example and also one PDF which explain their API. But I am using PHP to connect to the API & its not working. after connection I am just getting this response (0 193 "Netfonds Bank AS QUOTE-API version 1.6/20161128 real-time feed") & not able to execute any other command from API.

Here is my code that I tried

```
$socket  = fsockopen( "ssl://nfapi.netfonds.no", rand(8400,8405), $errno, $errstr, 100 ); 

$str = "(testmode:mode :OK)";

fwrite( $socket, $str ); 
echo "Reading response:\n\n";

//echo fread( $socket, 4096 );
while (!feof($socket)) {
        echo fread( $socket, 4096 );
    }
fclose( $socket );
```

I also tried this code, but same response

```
$g = stream_context_create (array("ssl" => array("capture_peer_cert" => true)));
// Create the server socket
//$r = stream_socket_server('ssl://nfapi.netfonds.no:'.rand(8400,8405),$errno,$errstr,STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN,$g);

$r = stream_socket_client("ssl://nfapi.netfonds.no:".rand(8400,8405), $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $g);
$cont = stream_context_get_params($r);
var_dump($cont["options"]["ssl"]["peer_certificate"]);

$str = "(testmode:mode :OK)";
fwrite($r, $str);
while (!feof($r)) {
        echo fread( $r, 4096 );
    }
fclose($r);
```

I have also installed SSL certificate on my server, but still my code is not working.

Comment: Maybe using Curl? Just an idea...

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Cagy79 , I tried Curl, but that also did not worked. May be I am doing some mistake.